# How to use toggle buttons instead of checkboxes/radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to use ON/OFF switches instead of Checkboxes and Radio buttons as shown in image to beautify website design.

[image: Toggle Buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps. [Check it out!](http://cssdeck.com/labs/a-simple-css-switch)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Switch toggle
  $('.Switch').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('On').toggleClass('Off');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons UI can be designed using css and you can use the toggle method of jquery.

http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/

After you have written the css for the buttons you just have to add css class and remove css class for the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do with your hand, basically you have structure like this:

## HTML

```
<div class='button' id='button-0'>
    <div class='button-switcher left' id='button-switcher-0'></div>
</div>
```

And with a script, you animate the inner div in this way:

## JQuery

```
var switchButton = function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('left, right');
   var versus = $(this).hasClass('right') ? 1 : -1; 
   var targetLeft = versus * parseInt($(this).parent().css('width')) / 2;
   $(this).animate({
       'left': '+=' + targetLeft + "px"
   });
}

$('.button-switcher').on('click', switchButton);
```

Take a look to the working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5ELx/1/)**.