# Convert checkbox to toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change checkbox to toggle button? There are no label tags in my input tags and I cant add them manually either, because I dont have access to core files. I can add jquery / script and or css to my files via CMS.

Here is the code i have for checkbox

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="savetheocean">
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: what do you want it to toggle?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102944/how-to-use-toggle-buttons-instead-of-checkboxes-radio-buttons

Comment: Can you please provide more detail

Answer (score 0):

basically this is how you can turn it to a toggle button:

```
$('input[name="savetheocean"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        //do something
    }
    else{
       //undo something
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

you can see a working Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/b4C7G/

Comment: Can you please share little more details on this? Other solutions i saw are not using input tags.

Comment: Thanks!! But I am really looking for toggle button instead of checkbox.. something like http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/ but its little complicated for me

Comment: you can just change the CSS

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmgLm.png]

**JSFiddle:**

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ujay/2/)

**CSS:**

```
a.toggler.on {
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a.toggler.off {
  background: red;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="toggler">&nbsp;</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="toggle"]').change(function () {
        $("a.toggler").toggleClass("off", this.checked)
    }).change();
})
```